# Error en consola $element, yo estoy usando $mdDialog de Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

Estoy tratando de resolver este problema que me sale en `consola` cuando estoy en la `url` del servidor donde esta mi proyecto, "PD: En mi `localhost` no me sale este error..."

[image]
Yo tengo esta vista con el controlador que usa esté.

```
.when('/aseguradora', {
            templateUrl: 'views/insuranceagentdashboard.html',
            controller: 'InsuranceagentdashboardCtrl'
        })
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
angular.module('virtualApp').controller('InsuranceagentdashboardCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', 'pager', 'Dialogs', function($http, $scope, pager, Dialogs) {..
```

Dentro del controlador yo tengo una función que ejecuta el modal, (Dialogs es un servicio):

```
$scope.showCosignerFormDialog = function(insuranceRequest) {
        Dialogs.cosignerFormdialog(insuranceRequest);
    }
```

En mi html tengo un `md-button` que ejecuta el `ng-click` :

```
<md-button class="md-color-green" ng-click="showCosignerFormDialog(insuranceRequest)">VER SOLICITUD</md-button>
```

Este es el servicio `Dialog`, que ejecuta el `modal`.

```
dialogs.cosignerFormdialog = function(insuranceRequest) {
        return $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'views/cosignerformdialog.html',
            autoWrap: false,
            controller: 'IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl',
            locals: {
                listing: insuranceRequest
            },
            preserveScope: true,            
            escapeToClose: false,
            fullscreen: true,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        });
    };
```

No se por que se esta produciendo este error en mi consola... Cuando estoy trabajando en el `localhost` todo funciona perfectamente.
**PD: Este error que ven en la consola se ejecuta cuando intento abrir un modal**

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para que veamos el problema?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahora mismo no se como crear ese error... no lo identifico aun, es hay el problema

Comment: lo definistes en los modulos de angular?, intentastes agregar el modulo $element?

Comment: Mira el enlace del error 
 https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$elementProvider%20%3C-%20$element%20%3C-%20IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl

Comment: Ni idea de como ayudarte, cuando me han pasado errores que en el local no pasan, la mayoría de las veces es por permisos en las carpetas donde se publican en el server, estará pasando algo así?

Comment: cambia dialogs por $mdDialog puedes ver mas en la [documentacion](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

Comment: @JackNavaRow donde dices que cambie dialogs? en el servicio?

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo permisos como cuales? de acceso a esas carpetas?

Comment: El error esta en una de las depedencias del controllador `IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl`, muestra el codigo de ese controlador.

Comment: Permisos de usuario me refiero, el usuario que ejecuta la aplicacion debe tener permisos para leer las carpetas del proyecto y para escribir en algunos casos, digo en general en IIS nose que servidor manejes, pero me ha pasado varias veces de esa forma, que alguna parte de la aplicacion no funciona porque el usuario que ejecuta la aplicacion en el server no puede leer algun archivo que se necesita.

Comment: @Einer y a todos los que han comentado... ya solucione este error, aparentemente fue por varios detalles, como actualizar la versión que se usaba en el servidor a la local, como quitar el $element que no se usaba... Eran varios detalles, pero ya se logro :)